# Unmanaged to Managed options: performance considerations

Tags: c#, c++-cli

Preliminary: The caller is a native EXE that exposes a type of "plugin" architecture. It is designed to load a DLL (by name, specified as a command line arg). That DLL must be native, and export a specific function signature. The EXE is C++, which isn't too important since the EXE is a black box (cannot be modified/recompiled). The native DLL can meet the application needs by completely implementing the solution natively, in said DLL. However, a requirement is to allow the real work (thus turning the native DLL into a thin wrapper/gateway) to be coded in C#. This leads me to 3 options (if there are more, please share):

1. Native DLL loads a C++/Cli DLL that internally makes use of a C# class library
2. Native DLL interacts with a C# COM object via CCW
3. Native DLL hosts CLR and makes calls to C# assembly

One more requirement is that not only does the native DLL need a way to send messages (call functions) on the C#, but the C# needs to be able to fire events/callback to the native DLL when certain extraordinary things occur (as opposed to shutting down and returning). Now this last thing I'm not sure how to handle in the 3rd option, but that is another question altogether.

So to the point: performance. Any info regarding those approaches (assuming they all meet the requirements)? From my investigation, my understanding is 2 would have more overhead than 1, but I'm not 100% confident, which is why I'm here. As for 3, I just don't have any info yet.

So if anyone has dealt with these (or knows of another elegant option), please chime in.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about performance, but 1 is definitely the easiest. The performance impact probably depends on how much data needs to be marshaled. Any info on the amount of data that needs to travel from EXE <--> DLL?

Comment: Communication is primarily from Native to Managed in the form of frequent small packets (256 bytes +or-). Communication from the Managed back to the Native will be rare, and in very short packets.

Answer (score 0):

I've done option 1 before, with reasonable success.  I don't remember any significant performance implications, though my application wasn't terribly performance-intensive.  It seems to me that if performance problems occur, a likely culprit might be the frequent, small native-to-managed transitions.  Would it be possible to batch those at the C++/CLI layer?